# iframed youtube playlist will not play second video

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to play a youtube playlist with two video's. Most times the second video won't start. It just has this load circle.

This is how I iframe the playliste:

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;list=PLQFDslj0TcumK8d3Cvu_0AcIHaj288n4U" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

What can I do?

It is iframed in another program but it is the request for the youtube playlist that fails somehow. When I start the computer at always plays both videos, but after 1-2 times it won't load the second movie.

My iframe code looks like this:

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gf2L2pHT3RQ?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;list=PLQFDslj0TcumK8d3Cvu_0AcIHaj288n4U" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: try to add listType=playlist in your querystring and check

Comment: I tried to add listType, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: if you share some working code it would be easy for us to solve this

Comment: I have added some information above, but that is all the code I write to get the videos iframed and streamed.